# $tds.attr('disabled','disabled'); not working to what i want

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code :

```
$tds = $(this).closest('tr').find(td input,select);
 $tds.attr('disabled','disabled');
```

make my table row uneditable,and also unclickable. However, i do have changing value of hidden input inside table row cells and its not changing if i used the aboce code. So i decided no to used it.

And now im looking for a make-around using this :

`document.getElementById("myText").readOnly = true;`,this work for single input, but i do want to have the input,select and button to be read only or not clickable of that clicked row.

Comment: use `$tds.prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: You are missing quote: find(td input,select); should be find('td input,select');

Comment: @ArunPJohny,still not working

Comment: can you share some context of the code like the html and the javascript function where it is used...

Comment: `$tds = $(this).closest('tr').find('td input,select');
$tds.prop('disabled', true);
$tds.prop('readonly', true);`

Comment: @ArunPJohny, ok sir wait, i think its working now, but not in IE8.wwaah

Comment: @ArunPJohny when i check $tds = $('tr').find('input,select');
alert($tds.eq(1).val());//value of this is change
$tds.attr('disabled','disabled');
alert($tds.eq(1).val());//value of this is delete but in other browser, value is empty and delete, which is the correct supposetedly values

Answer (score 2):

Use `input` in selector to get `input`,`select` and `button`, suppose you have click event on `tr` then you need to find the input elements those are `descendant` of tr which can be selected using [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) function.  Assign a common class to tr's which you want to bind the click event and using [Class Selector (“.class”)](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

Also use `prop` instead of `attr`

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as
>   the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the
>   .prop() method, [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

```
$('.trclass').click(function(){
   $(this).find('input').prop('readonly', true);
});
```

If you want to add click event to td instead of tr

```
$('.tdclass').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('tr').find('input').prop('readonly', true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Not an exact representation of your example, but illustrates the point: http://jsfiddle.net/ga0mz9zp/1/**

Wrap the `td input, select` in quotes, so:

```
$tds = $(this).closest('tr').find('td input,select');
$tds.attr('disabled','disabled');
```